# Editing the ".ghci" file when using stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have started using Stack and I can't find a .ghci file to edit (I wish to include `:set -XOverloadedStrings` and `:set prompt "ghci> "`).

To search for the `.ghci` file I used-

```
$ find -name ".ghci"
$
```

This did not return any search results. I have looked at the Stack documentation and I couldn't find information regarding editing the a `.ghci` file. Is it possible to save `:set -XOverloadedStrings` and `:set prompt "ghci> "` somewhere?

Comment: It should be either in `$HOME/.ghc/ghci.conf` or `$HOME/.ghci`. If neither exist, you can create it yourself...

Comment: Thanks, the did the job. I made a `.ghci` file and had to execute `chmod 644 /home/myUserName/.ghci` for it to work.

Comment: @Arnon Can you post that as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be either in `$HOME/.ghc/ghci.conf` or `$HOME/.ghci`. If neither exist, you can create it yourself...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the detail: [GHC User Guide - The .ghci and .haskeline files](http://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/master/users-guide/ghci.html#the-ghci-and-haskeline-files)

> When it starts, unless the -ignore-dot-ghci flag is given, GHCi reads and executes commands from the following files, in this order, if they exist:
>
> 1. ./.ghci
> 2. appdata/ghc/ghci.conf, where ⟨appdata⟩ depends on your system, but is usually something like C:/Documents and Settings/user/Application Data
> 3. On Unix: $HOME/.ghc/ghci.conf
> 4. $HOME/.ghci
>
> The ghci.conf file is most useful for turning on favourite options (e.g. :set +s), and defining useful macros.